# Jquery Compare two variables to see if they match, but one is out of scope?

Tags: jquery, variables, compare, match

For a small puzzle/memory game, I want to compare two pieces of the puzzle. If they are the same (have the same letter) i want to alert ('match'). I think I'm on the right way, but now one of the variables seems out of scope, because I don't know where in my code I should put it. So now it returns the second piece but the first stays undefined. Can you help me please? Much appreciate it!

Click on shuffle & show, after that click 2 pieces, you'll see the 'undefined' statement.
I'd like to know WHY it doesn't work and what will make it work and why :P

**HTML**

```
<button id="shuffle">Show and Shuffle</button>

<div id="container">
   <div class="choices"><div class="letter">A</div></div>
   <div class="choices"><div class="letter">B</div></div>
   <div class="choices"><div class="letter">C</div></div>
   <div class="choices"><div class="letter">A</div></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var amountofclicks = 0;
var firstcard = false;
var secondcard = false;

$('#shuffle').bind('click', function() {

    var divs = $("div.choices").get().sort(function() {
        return Math.round(Math.random());
    }).slice(0, 16);

    $(divs).appendTo(divs[0].parentNode).show();

});

$('.choices').bind('click', function() {

    if (amountofclicks < 2) {
        amountofclicks++;
        $(this).unbind('click');
        if (amountofclicks == 1) {
            firstcard = true;
            var txt = $(this).find('.letter').text();

        }

        if (amountofclicks == 2) {
            secondcard = true;

            var txt2 = $(this).find('.letter').text();
            alert(txt + ' ' + txt2);


        }

    }

});
```

[**JSFIDLLE WITH PROBLEM**](http://jsfiddle.net/QxSxh/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move your `txt` variable outside of the function so it can be read on the second click. Something like this:

```
var amountofclicks = 0;
var firstcard = false;
var secondcard = false;
var txt; // store here
```

You then need to remove the `var` from the line which initially sets the value:

```
if (amountofclicks == 1) {
    firstcard = true;
    txt = $(this).find('.letter').text(); // note: 'var' removed
}
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QxSxh/2/)

---

An alternative to using unsightly external variables is to set a `data` attibute on the container which has the value of the first card, something like this:

```
if (amountofclicks == 1) {
    firstcard = true;
    $("#container").data('first-letter', $(this).find('.letter').text());
}

if (amountofclicks == 2) {
    secondcard = true;

    var txt = $("#container").data('first-letter');
    var txt2 = $(this).find('.letter').text();
    alert(txt + ' ' + txt2);
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QxSxh/5/)

Comment: This isn't a scope issue. js doesn't have `if` scopes it's just that one of the if statements block isn't entered

Comment: @kidwon Very good point, I've amended the description of the problem.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

your first piece of code seems to be ok. The second piece not. It can get easier

```
var amountofclicks = 0;
var firstcard = false;
var secondcard = false;

$('#shuffle').bind('click', function() {

  var divs = $("div.choices").get().sort(function() {
    return Math.round(Math.random());
  }).slice(0, 16);

  $(divs).appendTo(divs[0].parentNode).show();

});

var firstChoise = null;

$('.choices').bind('click', function() {
  var $self = $(this);
  if (firstChoise == null) {
     firstChoise = $self.find('.letter').html();
  } else if (firstChoise == $self.find('.letter').html()) {
    alert('Choise: 2x'+firstChoise);
    firstChoise = null;
  } else {
    alert('Choise: 1x'+firstChoise+' 1x'+$self.find('.letter').html());
    firstChoise = null;
  }
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/czGZZ/1/